# how to overwrite wagtail function?

Tags: django, content-management-system, customization, wagtail, overwrite

i want to overwrite wagtail function
i want to add a column in admin user page
but i want to use

```
# add column
class SiteUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    note = models.TextField(verbose_name='note')
```

this way to add column
and i found wagtail is not allow to custom admin user view
in wagtail/users/views/users.py
so i want to overwrite function in users.py

```
def index(request, *args):
```

i want to edit it and change users column
how i can do that?

thanks for help~

Comment: I would suggest using a custom user model:  https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/advanced_topics/customisation/custom_user_models.html    and   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model

Comment: @DanSwain but. i have already use user model in other model and have data rows.... so when i use makemigrations will show error

Comment: I've actually switched to a custom user model mid-project, so I know it's possible.  Instructions here:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#changing-to-a-custom-user-model-mid-project   and  here:  https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2019/04/26/how-switch-custom-django-user-model-mid-project/

Comment: at last . i use hook and replace template to achieve my goal.. thanks everyone